# Integare libraby in custom MVC project

Tags: php, model-view-controller, mpdf

I have a custom PHP MVC project with the following structure:

```
app
    controller
    model
    view

core
    
public
```

I want to integrate some libraries like mPDF and PHPMailer. My question is where to place the files?

Should I add the files to `core` directory or use composer with `vendor` directory to integrate these files?

In case of composer method how to call one of the libraries?
In my project, I can just create an instance of a class like that `$user = new \app\controller\User()`
In this case to create instance from a library I have to include the autoload file first?

Answer (score -1):

use composer vendor repository, and namespaces of libs in your controllers, include them by `use ...;`, and yes, you need to use autoload